# Using a deep scan with JsonPath returns unexpected duplicates

Tags: java, jsonpath

I recently ran into a surprising result when querying a json string using the JsonPath library. When I use a deep scan (..) to query for an element in an array, the matching element gets returned twice in the results. For example, if I have a json document like:

```
{
  "container": [
   {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "foo",
    "value": "bar"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "hello",
    "value": "world"
  }
  ]
}
```

and I query for the value of the element with name "hello" using

```
List actual = JsonPath.read(jsonTwo,"$..*[?(@.name=='hello')].value");
```

I get the result

> ["world","world"]

I realize this is a trivial example and deep scan is overkill. However this is still an unexpected result. Is this a bug or intended behaviour? If it is intended, how do I avoid duplicate results when using a deepscan?

Comment: I only get one on my implementation, https://json-everything.net/json-path.  It may be a bug in the library you're using.